# Image URL in CSS is not working in Laravel 7

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 7.

```
Location of app.scss : resources/saas/app.scss
Location of app.css  : public/css/app.css
```

In app.scss

```
background-image: url("../public/images/homeheaderBg.jpg");
```

on Welcome.blade.php image is not displaying due to wrong Image URL

Wrong Image URL is :

```
http:localhost/images/homeheaderBg.jpg?325adac1518a8631dcc08fdb07bef837
```

It should

```
http:localhost/website_name/images/homeheaderBg.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
php artisan serve
```

in your terminal in this way your website link will be

```
http://localhost:8000
```

and in this way the **right** URL will become

```
localhost/images/homeheaderBg.jpg
```